# image upload and save path in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i did not get image upload and save `image` path in database
My table name is `uploadimage` and controller name is `upload.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view');
    }
    public function do_upload()

    {
        $status="";
        $msg="";
        $filename='product_pic';
        if(empty($_POST['title']))
        {
            $status="error";
            $msg="plz enter title";
        }
        if($status!="error")
        {
            $config['upolad_path']='./file/';
             $config['allowed_types']='gip|jpg|png';
             $config['max_size']=1024*0;
             $config['encrypt_name']=true;
             $this->load->library('upload',$config);
             if(!$this->upload->do_upload($filename))
             {
                 $status='error';
                 $msg=$this->upload->display_errors('','');
             }
             else
             {
                 $this->load->model('file_model');
                 $data=$this->upload->data();
                 $file_id=$this->file_model->insert_file($data['file_name'],$_POST['title']);
                 if($file_id)
                 {
                     redirect('Upload/view');
                 } 
         }
    }
```

Comment: post your view and model function too.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to have this

view.php

```
<?= form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload')?>
    <?= form_upload('userfile')?>
<?= form_close()?>
```

upload.php

```
function do_upload(){
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $ext = end((explode(".", $name))); # extra () to prevent notice

    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = 0;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else{
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        #you can choose from
        /*
           Array(
                 [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
                 [file_type]    => image/jpeg
                 [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
                 [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
                 [raw_name]     => mypic
                 [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
                 [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
                 [file_ext]     => .jpg
                 [file_size]    => 22.2
                 [is_image]     => 1
                 [image_width]  => 800
                 [image_height] => 600
                 [image_type]   => jpeg
                 [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
          )
        */

        $this->model->insert_data($upoad_data['file_name'], $upoad_data['full_path']);

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

model.php

```
function insert_data($name, $path_name){
    $data = array(
                  'name'    => $name,
                  'path'    => $path_name
                 );

    $this->db->insert('table', $data);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

With that, you upload your file, then get the data about the upload and insert it in db

Comment: why are we giving max size as 0 ?

Comment: Hi, if you check the [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html), the config parameter **max_size** The maximum size (in kilobytes) that the file can be. **Set to zero for no limit.** **Note: Most PHP installations have their own limit, as specified in the php.ini file. Usually 2 MB (or 2048 KB) by default.**

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet for uploading file with multiple file upload field in the form, saving uploaded file to custom directories and finally saving the file location path to the database

```
$input1 = $this->input->post('input1'); //Input field value
$input2 = $this->input->post('input2'); //Input field value
$photo1 = ''; //File field value
$photo2 = ''; //File field value

$config['upload_path'] = './photo_gallery/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']    = '';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

foreach($_FILES as $key=>$file) {
    //$key will be the field name
    $out_dir = "./photo_gallery/$key";
    if(!file_exists($out_dir)) {
        mkdir($out_dir, '0777', true);
    }
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $fileName = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $newName = sha1_file("./photo_gallery/$fileName") . "." . pathinfo("./photo_gallery/$fileName", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        rename("./photo_gallery/$fileName", "$out_dir/$newName");
        $$key = "$out_dir/$newName";    //This will assign values for $photo1 and $photo2 with new paths
    }              
}

$data_to_insert = array(
    'input1' => $input1,
    'input2' => $input2,
    'photo1' => $photo1, //Updated with new file path
    'photo2' => $photo2, //Updated with new file path
);

//pass variable $data_to_insert in model function that implements following
$success = $this->db->insert('my_table', $data_to_insert);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```