# How can I update a product picture in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to change the update function in my controller, 
Also added remove old picture function in model.

```
My update function in controller:

        public function update_product() {

    $id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    // remove old images
    $this->Product_model->remove_old_images($id);


        if(!$this->update->do_update('userfile')){
            $error = array('error'=>$this->update->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
        }else{
           //Main image
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = 547;
            $config['height'] = 430;

}

        // make thumb
        $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
        //$config2['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/'.'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
        $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $configThumb['width'] = 120;
        $configThumb['height'] = 112;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $configThumb);
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->image_lib->display_errors());
            redirect('/Product/cadeaupagina_aangeboden');
        }

         $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
         $this->image_lib->resize();


     $data = array(
    'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
    'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
    'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
    'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
    'product_foto' => 'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'],
    'product_foto_thumb' => 'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'],
     );

      $data['img'] = base_url().
      '/upload/new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
      $dataThumb['img'] = base_url().
     '/upload/thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];

     $this->Product_model->update($id, $data, $dataThumb);

     $this->load->view('cadeaubewerken',$data); 
     redirect('/Product/cadeaupagina_aangeboden');


}

My model update and remove image functions:



    public function get($id = '') {
            if (!empty($id)) {
                $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
            }
            return $this->db->get_where('products');
        }


                   public function update($id, $data, $dataThumb) {
        return $this->db->update('products', $data, array('product_id' => $id));
    }


         public function remove_old_images($id = null) {
            $i = 0; // num of delete files
            if ($id !== null && $this->get($id)->num_rows() == 1) {
                $fotos = $this->get($id)->row();
                $main = $fotos->product_foto;
                $thumb = $fotos->product_foto_thumb;
                if (is_file($this->up_path . $main)) {
                    unlink($this->up_path . $main);
                    $i++;
                }
                if (is_file($this->up_path . $thumb)) {
                    unlink($this->up_path . $thumb);
                    $i++;
                }
                return $i;
            } else {
                return $i;
            }

         }
```

My view file form:

```
       <tr>
             <h4>Cadeau naam</h4>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'value' => $product["product_naam"] , 'size'=>25));?></td>
           <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'product_id', 'name'=>'product_id', 'value' => $product['product_id']));?>
        </tr>


         <tr>
          <td><?php echo form_open_multipart('Product/upload'); ?> </td>
        </tr>

         <tr><td>
             <h4>Kies een categorie</h4>
         <select name="category_id">
        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) :
        if ($category->id ==  $product["category_id"]){
            echo '<option value="'.$category->id .'" selected>' . $category->name . '</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="'.$category->id .'">'.$category->name . '</option>';
            }
        endforeach; ?>
</select>
        </td>
        </tr> 

         <tr>
          <td><h4>Ophaal plaats</h4><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'value' => $product["ophaal_plaats"], 'size'=>25));?></td>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'value' => $product['ophaal_plaats']));?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
       <h4>Gebruik adres van mijn account</h4>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>Huidig cadeau profiel foto</h4>
                 <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

             <div class="image-upload">
                  <label for="file-input">
            <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'file', 'name'=>'product_foto', 'value' => $product['product_foto']));?>
             <h4>Cadeau profiel foto veranderen</h4>
            <input type="file" id="file1" name="userfile"/>
            </label>



            </div>



    <tr>
    <td><?php echo form_textarea(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'value' =>$product['product_beschrijving'], 'size'=>25));?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'value' => $product['product_beschrijving']));?>
    </tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Cadeau bewerken!" /></td>
</tr>
     </table>
    </form>
```

When I submit the form I get these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: KdGwcontroller::$update

Filename: controllers/KdGwController.php

Line Number: 42

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/KdGwController.php
Line: 42
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function do_update() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/KdGwController.php on line 42 Call Stack: 0.0004 244440 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0 0.0005 247232 2. require_once('/home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:315 0.0051 928288 3. call_user_func_array:{/home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:532}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:532 0.0051 929096 4. KdGwcontroller->update_product() /home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:532
    A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function do_update() on a non-object

Filename: controllers/KdGwController.php

Line Number: 42

Backtrace:
```

Comment: please explain "   'product_foto' => 'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext']"

Comment: That was a mistake I edited my question.

Comment: I have this in my view: 'value' => $product['product_foto']));?> but do I also have to mention the folder name where the picture is stored in?

Comment: is this problem solved or not?... if not solved please provide model function also.

Comment: Ok not solved yet, Ill edit my question so I can show you my model function

Comment: Check my updated question, it shows the model now

Comment: where is your file upload functionality?... without using file upload how it will work?

Comment: You have not added the upload functionality. Photo is not getting saved does not makes sense. You have to upload the uploaded image to your server and then save that server path to your database column. That is the usual workflow. Am i right?

Comment: This is not about uploading a picture, I already have that function but this is about updating a picture. So when a picture exists and you select a new picture it must add the new picture to the database and add in the 'upload' folder

Comment: Where are you trying to update that picture my friend? You cannot update picture in database unless it is a blob

Comment: oh so there is no way to update a picture in database? there must be a way to do this right in codeiginiter?

Comment: Yes. First you try to upload it to a folder. Unlink the previous file and then save the newly uploaded file path in database column

Comment: better refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659977/image-upload-and-save-path-in-database-using-codeigniter

Comment: Yes thats already done sir. I already have a upload function and when you select a picture and upload it , it makes a thumbnail called 'product_foto_thumb' and a normal picture which is called 'product foto', also those pictures get stored in my folder named 'upload'. Now what I'm trying to do is make a form so a user can select a new picture and update it and replace it with the old picture, you understand?

Comment: That is not my problem sir, that part is already done

Comment: @johnnydepp 1) Do the pic get stored in the folder as desired (image name must be same as in DB )??? so that i can analysis the problem .

Comment: yes the old picture is stored in the upload folder. So now i need to make a new function so the new picture will also uplload in the upload folder and replace it with the old picture and also the same in the database column.

Comment: 1)So first of all you need a unique key (id)  that represent image in DB .  2) fetch the old image name via that unique key and store that in a variable say '$img_name' . 2) upload the new image with the same name of  old pic but ensure to remove the old pic using unset(old file name here) before uploading  .

Comment: Can you show me code example for how i can do it

Comment: you update a picture the same way you upload it! just set CI uploader to overwrite old images and instead of inserting you update the field. you already have all the tools to do this as you've already created the upload function somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you do the same thing as when you upload initially, but instead, you use update queries and delete the old files after getting them from the database:

```
public function update_product() {
    $id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    // check if user with current id matches user who created the post
    // we dont want *smart* users to edit others posts
    if ($this->Product_model->get($id)->row()->user_id !== $_SESSION['user_id']) {
        show_error('Not authorized to edit this product.'); // this exits
    }
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        // remove old images
        $this->Product_model->remove_old_images($id);
        // upload new image
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            // handle errors here somehow
            //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            //$this->load->view('product_form', $error);
            echo $this->upload->display_errors(); // just for debug now
        } else {
            $upData = $this->upload->data();
            // set names
            $mainImage = 'new_' . $upData["raw_name"] . $upData['file_ext'];
            $thumbImage = 'thumb_' . $upData["raw_name"] . $upData['file_ext'];
            // Main image
            $configMain['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configMain['source_image'] = './upload/' . $upData["raw_name"] . $upData['file_ext'];
            $configMain['new_image'] = './upload/' . $mainImage;
            $configMain['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $configMain['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $configMain['width'] = 547;
            $configMain['height'] = 430;
            // Thumnail image
            $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/' . $upData["raw_name"] . $upData['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/' . $thumbImage;
            $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $configThumb['width'] = 120;
            $configThumb['height'] = 112;
            $this->image_lib->initialize($configMain);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            // delete original
            @unlink($upData['full_path']);
            // we add filesnames to db $data array
            $data['product_foto'] = $mainImage;
            $data['product_foto_thumb'] = $thumbImage;
        }
    }
    $data = array(
        'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
        'category_id' => !empty($this->input->post('category_id')) ? $this->input->post('category_id') : 0,
        'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
        'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
        'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
    );
    $this->Product_model->update($id, $data);
    echo 'Done'; // handle success however you want... just for debug now
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161420/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-how-can-i-update-a-product-picture-in-codeigniter).

Comment: Ok thanks Ill try this code out and see if it works, Also the model just stays the same right? the update function like this: public function update($id, $data) {
        return $this->db->update('products', $data, array('product_id' => $id));
    } and also the remove old image function stays the same right?

Comment: Also I have one more question, when the user enters the form and only changes other fields like text and not the picture, the fold picture gets deleted, But I only want the old picture to delete only when the user selects a new picture, Do I need to use Javascript with that? so when the user clicks on the button 'select new picture' the old picture gets removed

Comment: I don't get it. In my code it will only delete the old pictures if there is a file added and submitted.

Comment: Thats really weird, I'm using the same code and somehow even when I don't select a new picture, the old one gets removed when I submit the form. What could be the problem you think?

Comment: change `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])` to `$_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0`