# CodeIgniter, database with image name

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter, upload

I have a form that works fine, but the images are always registered with "1" in the database. actually the image database "image_name.jpg" or "image_name.png" should be saved with.

Where did I go wrong?
This İs My Controller;

```
public function send_Basvur_message(){

    $config['upload_path']          = './panel/uploads/basvur_v/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 4096;
    $config['overwrite']            = false;
    $config['encrypt_name']         = false;
    $config['remove_space']         = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->load->model("Basvur_model");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "Ad", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "E-posta", "trim|required|valid_email");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("subject", "Konu", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Mesaj", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("img_url", "img_url");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("captcha", "Doğrulama Kodu", "trim|required");

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        // TODO Alert...
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Action Completed');
        redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
    } else {

        $insert = $this->Basvur_model->add(
            array(
                "name"          => $this->input->post("name"),
                "email"         => $this->input->post("email"),
                "message"       => $this->input->post("message"),
                "subject"       => $this->input->post("subject"),
                "img_url"       => $this->upload->do_upload("img_url"),
                "created_at"    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            )
        );

        if($this->session->userdata("captcha") == $this->input->post("captcha")){

            $name = $this->input->post("name");
            $email = $this->input->post("email");
            $subject = $this->input->post("subject");
            $message = $this->input->post("message");
            $img_url = $this->input->post("img_url");

            $email_message = "{$name} isimli ziyaretçi. Başvuru Yaptı <br><b>Mesaj : </b> {$message} <br> <b>E-posta : </b> {$email}";

            if(send_email("", "Yeni Aday başvurusu | $subject", $email_message)){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
                // TODO Alert..
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
                // TODO Alert..
            }

        } else {
            //başarısıs
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Action Not Completed');
        redirect(base_url("basvuru"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->upload->do_upload()` returns bool hence the 1 stored in db, you want to call that then use `$this->upload->data()`, and pick out say `file_name` for the image name (not path as that may change), rtm: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data

Comment: I did, but it does not happen to me, I do not know where to write the code.

Comment: what is the type of the field?

Comment: img_url = varchar(255)  utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the `do_upload()` response instead of the file name.

what you can do is like following

```
$image_url = null;
if($this->upload->do_upload("img_url")){
    $image_url = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
}

$insert = $this->Basvur_model->add(
    array(
        "name"          => $this->input->post("name"),
        "email"         => $this->input->post("email"),
        "message"       => $this->input->post("message"),
        "subject"       => $this->input->post("subject"),
        "img_url"       => $image_url,
        "created_at"    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    )
);
```

save the image name if the `do_upload()` was successful unless it will save null

Comment: The "null" value comes from.

Comment: by default I gave it a null value which means empty. you can give it any value or keep it empty like `$image_url = ""';`

Comment: So what value should I give, let the image name register in the database.

Comment: @RasimAtaman replace `fileToUpload` with the name of your file input field in the `$image_url = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I don't want to bother you any more but it didn't    .$image_url = NULL;
if($this->upload->do_upload("img_url")){
    $image_url = $_FILES["upload_path"]["name"];
}

Comment: it's okay, I'm not bothered, I will try to help you fix your problem.
can you tell me if it's uploading the file in your directory ? does that work fine ?

Comment: yes loading, other form data all working properly. The only problem is to save the image to the database by name.

Comment: please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659977/image-upload-and-save-path-in-database-using-codeigniter